# Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2, customer-grid

Just upgraded to 1.9.2.2 and am getting this error when trying to view the customer grid in the backend.

I tried replacing:

```
/MYSITE/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
```

With a fresh copy with no luck!

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/MYSITE/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 514

Having a real headache trying to fix this error.

Comment: Please look this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070652/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a-non-object-in

Comment: The issue is that on that question the person set up a new attribute and then got this error, i got it out of nowhere and so have no cue where to find the issue!

Comment: Please check all extension related to customer, I think one file will rewrite your customer grid.

Comment: This site has a LOT of plugins, is there a way to see exactly which file is causing the error?

Comment: You need to debug one by one config file in that file you will get grid class overwrite by anyone extension or more.

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood, have you resolved the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

We had similar issue and it was because of during update new attribute wasn't created via resources process. renaming versions in core_resource table and running update again, error was gone. So it's 99% related to missed attribute